# jpackage pkg codesign -- appstore submission errors

Tags: java, macos, codesign, jpackage

I am following mostly the code sign and notarize instructions from this

[Code signing + notarization using jpackage utility isn't working on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60953329/code-signing-notarization-using-jpackage-utility-isnt-working-on-macos)

i.e going through each .dylib and jars and signing them. Finally sign the whole pkg and notarize.

Pkg  is successfully created and notarized but unable to submit to App Store because of the following errors. I can definitely run this pkg on my Mac with no issues.

What does item 3 mean? where do I get 3rd party cert? or what do I need to do...

Appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction to resolve these

Noticed Info.plist=not bound after notarization, perhaps this points to codesign not done properly?

Thanks in advance.

```
1. ERROR ITMS-90230: "Invalid product archive metadata. Error in keyPath [product-metadata.product-identifier]. Please re-build your
archive with an up-to-date version of Xcode, and submit again."

2. ERROR ITMS-90230: "Invalid product archive metadata. Error in keyPath [product-metadata.product-version]. Please re-build your
archive with an up-to-date version of Xcode, and submit again."

3. ERROR ITMS-90237: "The product archive package's signature is invalid. Ensure that it is signed with your "3rd Party Mac Developer
Installer" certificate."

4. ERROR ITMS-90249: "The product archive is invalid. The value of the LSApplicationCategoryType key in the Info.plist is Unknown,
which is not a UTI for a valid category. For more details, see
"Submitting your Mac apps to the App Store"."

5. ERROR ITMS-90254: "The product archive is invalid. The installer package may not include install scripts."

6. ERROR ITMS-90264: "The lowest minimum system version [none] in the Product Definition Property List must equal the
'LSMinimumSystemVersion' value [10.9] in the 'Info.plist'."

7. ERROR ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox"
entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements
property list: [(
"MyApp-app.pkg/Payload/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp",
"MyApp-app.pkg/Payload/MyApp.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/lib/jspawnhelper"
)] Refer to App Sandbox page at
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox for
more information on sandboxing your app."
=========
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case(ERROR ITMS-90237), expired certificates were not removed from the Keychain. (New ones were automatically generated by XCode)